# Selenium Webdriver - Keys not being sent to search boxes

Tags: browser-automation, python-3.9

I am starting to use Selenium Webdriver (Chrome) and while pages open automatically keys are not being sent for some reason. For example, I open google.com, and I use a "BY.ID" to aim at the search box by it's ID and send "Hi" but for some reason, it doesn't send the keys, I tried looking at the Selenium documentation but It kinda left me more confused, anybody knows why keys aren't being sent? Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/thras/Desktop/Chromedriver/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.youtube.com')

title = browser.title

browser.implicitly_wait(3)

text_box = browser.find_element(By.ID,"search").send_keys('Hi')
```

Comment: Apparently, as I keep trying, I managed to do it by modifying this line: 

text_box = browser.find_element(By.NAME, value="q")

Syntax was an issue it seemed. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/thras/Desktop/Chromedriver/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.google.com')

title = browser.title

browser.implicitly_wait(3)

text_box = browser.find_element(By.NAME, value="q")
text_box.send_keys('Hiii')
```

fixed, it was syntax issue it seems, I needed to add "value" before the actual ID

Comment: It looks like you can use `by` and `value` when calling `find_element` but you don't have to, you can just use 2 positional arguments.